# MsBuild with SSDT is not publishing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, sql-server-data-tools

I'm using [microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
which has been made for VSDBCMD, and changed it in a way that instead of having the argument with this:

```
"/a:Deploy /dd+ /dsp:Sql /manifest:DatabaseProjectName.deploymanifest"
```

I have this

```
"/Action:Publish /SourceFile:""C:\Builds\2" + BuildDetail.BuildDefinition.FullPath + "\Binaries\MyDBTest.dacpac"" /Profile:""C:\MyTFSPublishData\DevEnv.publish.xml"
```

And instead of VSDBCMD, clearly I aim to the sqlpackage.

I make my build definition, and queue my build and it seems to work.

```
$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin\sqlpackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"C:\Builds\2\LaboratoryTFS\DeployToDevEnv\Binaries\MyDBTest.dacpac" /Profile:"C:\MyTFSPublishData\DevEnv.publish.xml
Publishing to database 'MyDBTest' on server '(localdb)\v11.0'.
Initializing deployment (Start)
Initializing deployment (Complete)
Analyzing deployment plan (Start)
Analyzing deployment plan (Complete)
Updating database (Start)
Creating [dbo].[MyFirstTable]...
Creating [dbo].[MySecondTable]...
Update complete.
Updating database (Complete)
Successfully published database.
```

However on the database it isn't doing anything.

And when I run the generated sql code on the sql management studio it does.

**@Edit**: When I publish from my Visual Studio, it also works wonderfully, but since I want this to be an automatic process, I find myself *answer reliant*.

What am I missing?

TIA

Comment: We ended up splitting it into a "build" command to build the dacpac and then used SQLPackage to publish the dacpac using a publish profile. Not exactly the answer you want, but it looks like you're pushing your changes to the (localdb) instance - SSDT's "debug" DB. Either your publish profile is pointing to the wrong DB or something else is redirecting it to (localdb).

Comment: I'm actually testing it aiming to '(localdb)\v11.0' to see if it works or not, that at least is ok. Unless you tell me that doing this won't work, in which case I'll try aiming to an external source

Comment: I can't say for sure that it won't work. Just that we use something like this:         
msbuild .\MySQLProject\MySQLProject.sqlproj /t:build /p:Configuration="Local"         
sqlpackage /a:publish /tsn:localhost /sf:.\MySQLProject\sql\Local\MySQLProject.dacpac /pr:.\MySQLProject\Publish\Local.publish.xml